# Make visual presentation of confusion matrix based on multi label classification

Tags: python, confusion-matrix, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to make a visual presentation of my multilabel classification, but I can't seem to make anything work. Right now I just have this output, which is the 4 labels I have and their respective confusion matrix:

[image]

Do you guys have a tip for turning this into a more visual/plotted solution?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69723367/make-visual-presentation-of-confusion-matrix-based-on-multi-label-classification) you can find answer for your question.

Comment: @AyseN. the link is not working